# Add SSL CA File Using urllib2

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, urllib2

I need to be able to specify SSL certificate CA root, yet be able to insert HTTP cookie with Python 2.7.10 `urllib2` library

```
ssl_handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(ssl_handler)
opener.addheaders.append(("Cookie","foo=blah"))
res = opener.open(https://example.com/some/info)
```

I know urllib2 supports `cafile` param, where should I use it in my code ?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319430/how-do-i-have-python-httplib-accept-untrusted-certs

Answer (score 5):

[`urlopen` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data[, timeout[, cafile[, capath[, cadefault[, context]]]]])

so, please try:

```
urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/some/info", cafile="test_cert.pem")
```

or

```
cxt = ssl.create_default_context(cafile="/path/test_cert.pem")
urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/some/info", context=cxt)
```

Comment: I could use `urllib2.urlopen`, but I don't know how to add cookies to the request other than via opener object.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to specify a CA file was added in python 2.7.9, according to the documentation, and is only available in the urlopen call, as as noted in the previous answer.

So you do need to change opener.open() to urllib2.urlopen.
In order to have it still use the opener, call
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
before the urlopen call

This is the only way I found to have all of (cookies & login authentication & CA cert specified)