# httplib.HTTPSConnection issue : CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python

I'm trying to access a website with httplib library but i'm getting this error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

```
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection('IP', 443)
c.request(method,url);
```

Because the certificate is self-signed. How can I disable the certificate verification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How do I have python httplib accept untrusted certs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319430/how-do-i-have-python-httplib-accept-untrusted-certs)

```
httplib.HTTPSConnection(hostname, timeout=5, context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
```