# SSL_CERTIFICATE_FAILED error + corporate proxy urrlib2

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2

I have having trouble accessing `HTTPS` sites using `urllib2`. Here's what I've got:

```
import urllib2 
import ssl

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https':'http://username:password@proxy:port',
                              'http': 'http://username:password@proxy:port'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(), 
                              urllib2.HTTPSHandler(), 
                              proxy)
urllib2.install(opener)

url_secure = 'https://www.google.com'
url_nonsecure = 'http://www.google.com'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url_nonsecure)
d = response.read()
response.close()
print d
```

The above runs without issue. However, if i try to run the above using

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_secure)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "google_maps.py", line 25, in <module>
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_secure)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
context=self._context)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268548/python-ignore-certicate-validation-urllib2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) it seemed like the problem could be solved by creating a new context. So I tried both:

```
ctx=ssl._create_unverified_context()
```

and

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

and ran

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_secure, context = ctx)
d = response.read()
response.close()
print d
```

which both threw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "google_maps.py", line 25, in <module>
response = urllib2.urlopen(url_secure, context=ctx)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
context=self._context)
File "/Users/username/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

How can I access https sites?

Comment: Don't disable certificate validation. Instead get the CA used by the corporate proxy and set it as cafile in the call to urlopen.

Comment: Thanks, how do I find/get the CA?

Comment: Ask you IT department or export it from the certificate manager of the browser or similar.

Comment: Ah! ok. that was it. thanks!

Comment: Ed Randall mentioned a PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 env variable that disables your security.  To enable a particular root CA, python seems to require defining an SSL "context" in one's own code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319430/how-do-i-have-python-httplib-accept-untrusted-certs